# How to use Prometheus Time Series database for Jmeter live reporting?

Tags: jmeter, grafana, prometheus

How can I use Prometheus database for Jmeter live reporting ?. I want to execute Jmeter in Non GUI mode and get live reporting in Grafana using prometheus as a database..

Comment: I have been through this link but didn't understand: https://github.com/johrstrom/jmeter-prometheus-plugin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the steps to follow
  1. Download the source code from https://github.com/johrstrom/jmeter-prometheus-plugin and build it using `"maven clean package"`.
 2. Two jar files will be generated in target folder copy them and keep it in JMeter lib/ext folder.
 3. Open JMeter, to your thread group add Prometheus Listener which will be in Listener.
 4. Run JMeter and metrics will be rendered on `http://localhost:9270/metrics`

Comment: Docs say you only need the first jar, the biggest one. The original-*.jar is already included in the first one